# PID of multiple children forked off the same parent

Tags: c++, fork

so I have this main function:

```
int main() {
cout << "Before fork: " << getpid() << endl;

pid_t pid;
pid = fork();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    if (pid < 0) {
        cout << "ERROR: Unable to fork.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    else if (pid == 0) {
        switch(i) {
            case 0:
                for (int b = 0; b < 10; ++b) {
                    cout << "b " << getpid() << endl;
                    cout.flush();
                }

                break;
            case 1:
                for (int c = 0; c < 10; ++c) {
                    cout << "c " << getpid() <<endl;
                    cout.flush();
                }                    
                break;
            case 2:
                for (int d = 0; d < 10; ++d) {
                    cout << "d " << getpid() << endl;
                    cout.flush();
                }                    
                break;
            default:
                cout << "ERROR" << endl;
                return 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int a = 0; a < 10; ++a) {
            cout << "a " << getpid() << endl;
            cout.flush();
        }
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

The point of this program is run four processes at the same time, each printing out a character a certain amount of times. Whenever I run the program, I get that the children I've made all have the same PID. Is it supposed to be that way? If not/so, why?

Answer (score 1):

You only created one child, which then runs a loop in which it checks three times that it actually is the child. To create three children, you need three calls to `fork`. I.e., something like this:

```
if ((pid1 = fork()) == 0) {
  // work for first child
  exit(0);
}
if ((pid2 = fork()) == 0) {
  // work for second child
  exit(0);
}
if ((pid3 = fork()) == 0) {
  // work for third child
  exit(0);
}
// work for parent, then:
wait(pid1);
wait(pid2);
wait(pid3);
```

Comment: Where would I insert fork() statements such that 3 children are created? I moved the fork() I had into my for loop, but I think that went infinite and crashed everything.

Comment: EDIT: I solved my issue by changing my break statements into return 0's in order to prevent infinite calls to fork(). 4 different PID's were printed, nothing crashed, so I presume that it's a proper solution.

Comment: Doing three different things by having a for loop that does (almost) nothing but a big switch statement is not what would pass code review where I work, but hey, it’s your code, I assume you have a good reason for doing it that way.